# ArcGIS Online - Programmatically Upload Tabular Data Source

Tags: arcgis-online

I have some ArcGIS Online maps and want to reference a simple data source like a CSV or XML file.  I know that I can upload the file, but is there a way I could programmatically upload the data file on a scheduled basis?  Or in other words, is there an API that I can use in a program or script that allows me to send data files to my ArcGIS Online storage location?

The first thought I had was to write a program that connects as me and sends the file by POSTing to the web service, but there might be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Add Item](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/02r3/02r30000008q000000.htm) and [Publish Item](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/02r3/02r300000080000000.htm) operations in the REST API.  There are some good examples of using the REST API with Python on Github (e.g., the [Esri AGO Tools repository](https://github.com/Esri/ago-tools) and [oevans's GIST](https://gist.github.com/oevans/6128188). There are some in the ArcGIS Javascript API, too.

Comment: I should have checked Github, didn't realize there is so much GIS/Python code available.  I haven't tried it yet, but since the second code link shows how to get the token and use it I'm sure this is the way to go.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is the ArcGIS Portal [REST API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000mt000000), which should cover your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is the [ArcGIS REST API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000mt000000), which Petr mentioned, but there is also the [ArcGIS JavaScript API](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/portal.html) as well as an [experimental Python API](https://github.com/Esri/arcpy-server-util-rest) for ArcGIS Server (not the same but there is probably some overlap) on the ESRI Github site.

What language and platform are you developing for?

Comment: I found the REST API, but not specifically how to upload a file to ArcGIS Online yet.  Since it's REST, I can use just about anything here to communicate with it.  We're mostly an MS shop and I can use C# or PowerShell to test it, but we can also use Python, whatever is best to make it happen.

Comment: I checked into the ArcGIS JavaScript API and found a video on developing for ArcGIS Online - http://video.esri.com/watch/1218/developing-with-arcgis-online.  At 41 minutes it mentions generating a token and using Content/AddItem, but no example.  I found some other resources that will keep me busy with this for a while now.